# NavigationLink: show intermediate view with a survey and after it is closed - proceed to "destination" view

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

In my fitness application a user sees a list of available trainings, this list is implemented by the following structure

```
ForEach(self.mainData.journeys) { journeyDraft in
                        NavigationLink(destination:
                            VStack { [data] }
                        )
}
```

(see full code below)

**[data]** contains a long **if { } else { } if { } else { }** block including multiple scenarios - SetView/WeekView/BuildWeekView/GenerateJourney (lets call them all **GoToView**), depending on training settings and state (new training or already started one).

Here comes a problem.. The user clicks on some training from the list and before sending the user to appropriate view (**GoToView**) from NavigationLink I check if he has completed his fitness level survey:

```
self.mainData.customerData?.fitnessLevel != nil
```

And if he has not yet, I need to show him a survey view first. And only after he completes the survey - he is sent further to **GoToView**.. (If he has already filled the survey, he is sent straight to **GoToView**, not survey view is shown)

How would you recommend implementing this intermediate View so that when he answers my question, he proceeds to GoToView ?

I have 4 different scenarios (SetView, WeekView, BuildWeekView, GenerateJourney) inside that if/else block and I don't wanna include the survey view inside each of them.. I want to find some way to show the view BEFORE sending the user to NavigationLink's destination (**GoToView**).

Any help is appreciated!

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ProfileView()
                .opacity(self.showProfile ? 1 : 0)
            VStack {
                Image(customImage: ((self.thisSession.profile.photo != nil) ? self.thisSession.profile.photo : Constants.defaultProfileImage)!)!
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showProfile.toggle()
                    }
                List {
                    ForEach(self.mainData.journeys) { journeyDraft in
                        NavigationLink(destination:
                            VStack {
                                
                                // if fitness survey IS COMPLETED but journey was not yet created
                                if (self.mainData.customerData?.fitnessLevel != nil && self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!] == nil) {
                                    
                                    // if it's NOT a single day training, no need to return to it? why..?
                                    if journeyDraft.type != Constants.singleDay {
                                        VStack {
                                            //Text("Section 1").foregroundColor(.blue)
                                            DeferView { BuildWeekView(journeyDraftId: journeyDraft.journeyId, customerData: self.mainData.customerData)
                                            .navigationBarHidden(true)
                                            .navigationBarTitle("")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        
                                        VStack {
                                            DeferView { GenerateJourney(schedule: [:], tools: [:], journeyDraft: journeyDraft,  thisSession: self.thisSession, goto: Constants.goToDay)
                                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                                                .navigationBarTitle("")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                // if fitnessLevel is set and this is not a first launch
                                } else if (self.mainData.customerData?.fitnessLevel != nil && self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!] != nil) {
                                    // multiple day training
                                    if (self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!]!.type! == Constants.singleDay) {
                                                                        VStack {
                                                                            WeekView(journey: self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!]!)
                                                                            .navigationBarHidden(true)
                                                                            .navigationBarTitle("")
                                                                        }
                                                                    } else {
                                                                            // it's a single day training
                                                                        VStack {
                                                                            SetView(journey:self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!]!,day:self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!]!.days.keys.first!)
                                                                            .navigationBarHidden(true)
                                                                            .navigationBarTitle("")
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                        
                                // if survey is not completed and this is a first launch (but we need to run GenerateJourney then
                                } else if (self.mainData.customerData?.fitnessLevel == nil) {
                                   // HERE WE NEED TO SHOW THE SURVEY AND AFTER IT IS COMPLETED - DO THE SAME AS ABOVE
                                }

                            }
                        ) {
                            Image(customImage: journeyDraft.image!)!
                                .resizable()
                                .renderingMode(.original)
                                .frame(height: 150, alignment: .leading)
                                .opacity( (self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!] == nil) ? 1 : 0.5 )
                                .overlay(
                                    Text("\(journeyDraft.name!) : \(journeyDraft.type!)")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        .foregroundColor((self.mainData.userJourneys[journeyDraft.journeyId!] == nil) ? .white : .red)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .opacity(self.showProfile ? 0 : 0.6)
            
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using tags in NavigatingLink